# remove duplicates from each group after .GroupBy()

Tags: c#, linq

```
var groupedList = mylist.GroupBy(mytype => mytype.Category).ToList()
```

`groupedList` is now an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Category, MyType>>`

Now I would like to do a Distinct() on a specific property of MyType for each `IGrouping<Category, MyType>` to remove the duplicates. The return value needs to be the same type as `groupedList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a solution.  It's not ideal in terms of performance, in that the `GroupBy` at the end is a bit redundant, mostly to get the proper types but it's not a super expensive operation, so this should be good enough.

```
groupedList = groupedList.SelectMany(group =>
    group.DistinctBy(mytype => mytype.SomeProperty)
        .Select(item => new
        {
            key = group.Key,
            element = item,
        }))
.GroupBy(pair => pair.key, pair => pair.element)
.ToList();
```

If you create a `Group` class, like so:

```
public class Group<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private IEnumerable<TElement> elements;

    public Group(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
    {
        this.elements = elements;
        Key = key;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return elements.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public static Group<TKey, TElement> CreateGroup<TKey, TElement>(
    TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> elements)
{
    return new Group<TKey, TElement>(key, elements);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
groupedList = groupedList.Select(group =>
    (IGrouping<string, Foo>)CreateGroup(group.Key,
        group.DistinctBy(mytype => mytype.SomeProperty)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. I'm not processing that much data so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of `Distinct` that takes an instance of `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Create a class that implements that interface where `T` is mytype.GetType(). The implementation should make the comparison using your property value.

Comment: There's more to the problem than just that

Comment: I already have a .DistinctBy() method that can do that. The problem is the grouping.

Comment: @user1151923 What do you mean the "problem is the grouping" I think you should explain how Distinct DistinctBy doesn't return what you expected

Comment: @Alan The result won't be of the proper type, as is stated in the question itself...

Comment: @user1151923 You should include, in the question, that you already have a `DistinctBy` implementation, both so that it's clear solutions can use it, and so that readers don't assume that that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @user1151923 how is calling distinct before grouping not solving your problem?

Comment: @Gusdor He only wants duplicate values *within the same group* to be removed, not duplicate values from other groups to be removed.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks @Servy. Ambiguous question is ambuiguous.

Comment: @Gusdor It's not ambiguous at all.  "I would like to do a Distinct() [...] for each IGrouping[...]".  It's very clear that it wants to do the distinct on each group.  There is no ambiguity there.